# Diferença entre comandos onClick no React

Tags: javascript, react, onclick, callback

Quando se tratando de funções de callback no ReactJS, qual é a diferença entre as opções abaixo?

1. `onClick={() => this.onFunctionCickCall()}`
2. `onClick={this.onFunctionClickCall()}`
3. `onClick={this.onFunctionClickCall.bind(this)}`
4. `onClick={this.onFunctionClickCall}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Todos fazem a mesma coisa porém alguns usam uma syntax mais atual.

**Caso 1:** `onClick={() => this.onFunctionClickCall()}`
Este é o modelo mais novo de se escrever pois você não precisa dar um "fix" no bind da função dentro do construtor. [Veja a documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render)

Também é bom dizer que neste caso ele retorna uma função que executa outra função. Útil quando você precisa passar algum tipo de parametro para as função.

Ex.:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}
```

Você também poderia escrever assim (Exemplo abaixo), que teria o mesmo efeito do caso acima.

ex.:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  handleClick = () => () => {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>;
  }
```

**Caso 2 e 4:**
Nestes caso faz necessário o uso do "bind fix" no construtor. [Veja a documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-constructor-es2015). Ou usar [arrow function syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal) não tão usada porém mais simples de escrever.

Nestes casos se você tentar usar com o `()` no final irá executar assim que o código for carregado.

Ex.:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}
```

**E o caso 3:** `onClick={this.onFunctionClickCall.bind(this)}`

É só um jeito de dar um "bind fix" sem precisa colocar dentro do construtor como foi usado no caso 2 ou 4.

De todos os jeitos que você escrever vão estar certo, porém alguns são syntax mais atuais/simples porém é interessante você saber o que está acontecendo por trás antes. [Essa pode ser uma boa leitura para você entender mais](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/react-create-class-vs-es6-class-components/)